# Would this question be enough to meet the criteria of game-identification?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have been looking for a game for a few years now. I know that it's Mega-Man, and I know the platform it was on, but all of my Mega-Man fan friends tell me that they don't know which game it is.

I remember a good deal about the opening of the game, but I don't remember which game it is. I also do not have a screenshot of the game.

Would this be enough to get it identified, or no? I just want to make sure I understand how well this would fit the criteria before I post the question.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that my friends know more about the Gameboy games than the PlayStation, which is the console I am referring to.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mega_Man_video_games just to get you started, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it would not be enough. We require a screenshot, or some other audiovisual artifact, of the game in question.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to be sure instead of once again wasting my efforts to leave my search at a dead end from the lack of an answer. I hope to one day figure out which game it is...

Comment: @Kendra Even if you can't ask your question on-site, you could always come into chat and ask. You might be able to get your answer that way.

Comment: @Kendra There aren't that many on the PS so I should probably be able to help you here in chat.

Comment: @Yuki I hadn't thought of that, actually. I'll have to when I get home. Now that I have an original PlayStation, I want to rebuild my collection. I already have my all-time favorite game, so a good start.